# How To Enable Image Upload In CKEditor5 (Classic Editor)?

Tags: image, ckeditor, editor, ckeditor5, image-upload

It is two days that I am trying to add image upload feature to the CKEditor but I did not succeed.

When I click on **image upload icon** in toolbar, it opens a modal to choose an image (from your computer) to load it in the editor.
The problem is that it does not open the image I choose.

I use CDN for CKeditor5 :

Config For CKEditor 5 that I have put it in js file:

ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#questionMainTextId' ), {
language: {
ui: 'fa',
},
} )
.catch( error => {
console.error( error );
} );

Please put a sample of **ckeditor5 (*Classic Editor*)**
as an answer for this question.

**Thank You All For Helping !**

Answer (score 0):

I also dealt with this issue. The problem is that Ckeditor5 in Predefined CKEditor 5 builds for some reason does not have an image download module. Therefore, you need to either write it yourself, or use an online constructor with one of the standard modules

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/image-upload/image-upload.html

https://ckeditor.com/blog/managing-images-with-ckeditor-5/